# Best way to scale size of camera picture before saving to SD

Tags: android, bitmap, jpeg

The code below is executed as the jpeg picture callback after TakePicture is called. If I save data to disk, it is a 1280x960 jpeg. I've tried to change the picture size but that's not possible as no smaller size is supported. JPEG is the only available picture format.

```
 PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
   FileOutputStream out = null;
   Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length); 
   Bitmap sbm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 640, 480, false);
```

data.Length is something like 500k as expected. After executing BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(), bm has a height and width of -1 so it appears the operation is failing.

- It's unclear to me if Bitmap can handle jpeg data. I would think not but I have seem some code examples that seem to indicate it is.
- Does data need to be in bitmap format before decoding and scaling?
- If so, how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your surfaceCreated, you code set the camara's Picture Size, as shown the code below:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
            p.set("jpeg-quality", 70);
            p.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
            p.setPictureSize(640, 480);
            camera.setParameters(p);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```